# How to set LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 in Raspbian?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, locale

I know the answer in the thread [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/a/790373/25388), by which I cannot change the fields `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` to the corresponding values. I am setting up [retropie](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/manual-installation) in my Raspberry Pi 3B Raspbian the newest OS. 
My `locale`

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE= # TODO empty! but should be en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB:UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL= # TODO empty but should be en_GB.UTF-8
```

OS: Raspbian
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3B

Comment: Why do you want to set `LC_ALL`? It isn't necessary, it's an override. Likewise `LANGUAGE`. See [`locale(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) for details.

Comment: @StephenKitt It is just said so in the manual of `retropie`, which is the only reason.

Comment: That sounds somewhat broken (or overkill). Anyway, have you tried the fix that's mentioned in the documentation? `sudo update-locale LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"` etc.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, I have tried it unsuccessfully. It does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/locale.gen` then uncomment the following line:

```
 en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Run:

```
locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
update-locale en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Verify it; `locale` :

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Comment: If you get an error starting like this `perl: warning: Setting locale failed.` And if the following lines mention "(unset)" variables, it is needed to set those variables before being able to execute `update-locale`. So to recap, the solution should be:  - 1. locale-gen,   - 2. export variables  - 3. update-locale

Comment: @GAD3R I am getting this error: `$ sudo update-locale LANGUAGE="en_GB.UTF-8"
*** update-locale: Warning: LANGUAGE (en_GB.UTF-8) is not compatible with LC_ALL (). Disabling it.`

Answer (score 0):

StephenKitt's proposal: Do not set up `LC_ALL` and `LANGUAGE` because you do not need them here. 
Tested, this approach works too.